# How to import music from CD and display its artwork?

Tags: release-juno, music

I'm trying to use Music, and I am unable to get it to work, and there are no instructions.

I try to use Import music. I tells me that the song from the CD are already in my music folder. They are not, it's empty.
I try the other option - load music from an external disk, and the app crashes. Continually. It doesn't work again until I dismount the drive.

**Question 1: How do I import music in the Music app?**

So I use Sound Juicer to rip the CD, and Picard to ensure the tags are ok. Music can play the files that are now in it's library, but it doesn't show the album art, even though Picard sees it.

**Question 2: How do I get the artwork as shown on your website: elementary.io**

To me, this is a deal breaker, as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find your music in the music file and from there you can move it to the music folder.If you go to files-music your music will be there.
If you open the music app and import music from music file that should work for you.
Hope this helps.
Sorry you are having trouble

Comment: That doesn't help. As I said, my music is on CD. Using load from external drive crashes music app. So I used Juicer to rip it into music folder. At that point import doesn't work, it says they are already there. And I can play them but there is no album art.

Comment: So I had typed more but this support app said I was typing too slow and refused my edit.

Comment: Rythm box works fine. I could use that and remove music. But the point of eOS is that it comes with what I need. But it doesn't.  Thats false advertising. It also says its a replacement for windows. More false advertising since I have to replace built in apps. I'm left with the impression that open source isn't worth using.

Comment: if you want me to pay for eOS it better work.

Comment: I apologize for losing my cool. In my defense

1) I seem to get the run-around from elementary support. (When I reported this same issue in Loki, my support request was closed as 'out of topic'. I thought with the new release things might have changed.)
2) This form is unfriendly and difficult to use on my smart-phone. Even on the desktop it's not clear how to use it.
3) The more I use eOS, the more the Elementary.io site seems deceptive.

The upside is I don't have to use this software. I wouldn't recommend it to other Windows users either. 

BTW - how do I get a refund?